# Adding flash messages to connect-ensure-login

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I use passport-local with connect-ensure-login, as it allows me to easily redirect back to the page the user initially wanted (but got redirected to login because he wasn't logged in). How could I show a flash message after the user gets redirected to the log in page by connect-ensure-login? I use connect-flash for flash messages

Answer (score 0):

Decided to necro this as the other answer on here does not really address the OP's enquiry, and maybe others will face the same issue.

`connect-ensure-login`'s implementation is pretty straightforward (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login/blob/master/lib/ensureLoggedIn.js#L34)). Adding another option to pass a Flash message through to the middleware is pretty trivial:

```js
module.exports = function ensureLoggedIn(options) {
    if (typeof options == 'string') {
        options = { redirectTo: options }
    }

    options = options || {};

    var flash = options.failureFlash;

    if (options.failureFlash) {
        if (typeof options.failureFlash == 'string') {
            flash = { type: 'failure', message: flash };
        }

        flash.type = flash.type || 'failure';
    }

    var url = options.redirectTo || '/login';
    var setReturnTo = (options.setReturnTo === undefined) ? true : options.setReturnTo;

    return function(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.isAuthenticated || !req.isAuthenticated()) {
            if (setReturnTo && req.session) {
                req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl || req.url;
            }

            if (flash) {
                req.flash(flash.type, flash.message);
            }
            return res.redirect(url);
        }

        next();
    }
}
```

I'll try to PR this version to the main branch of `connect-ensure-login` if I have time. In the meantime, you could save version locally (let's say `libs/ensureLoggedIn.js`) and use it as follows:

```js
const ensureLoggedIn = require('../libs/ensureLoggedIn');

// pass a flash object or string as an option
const flashObj = { type: 'authFailure', message: 'Authentication is required' }; // or simply pass the message string and 'failureFlash' would be assigned as the flash object's type

app.get('/admin', ensureLoggedIn({ 
    redirectTo: '/login',
    failureFlash: flashObj
}, ... );
```

Using `req.flash('authFailure');` after the redirect works in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Add message before redirection.

```
req.flash('login_error_msg', 'Login Error!!')
```

Define your flash message tag (login_error_msg) in app.use with locals

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.login_error_msg = req.flash('login_error_msg');
    next();
});
```

Create conditions for handling error_msg. I am using ejs engine make it according to you

```
<%if(login_error_msg.length>0){ %>
   <div class="alert alert-danger"> <%= login_error_msg %></div>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Do I have to add a middleware for the req.flash before ensureLoggedIn? Since ensureLoggedIn acts as middleware too, I can't add the message before redirection...

Comment: in app.js file
    const flash = require('connect-flash')

and then use this before app.use middleware function
     app.use(flash());

Comment: I only want to use it on one page though, so there is no point in setting it in locals...

Comment: You can do that
 res.locals.login_error_msg = req.flash('login_error_msg', 'Login Error!!');
It runs when you got an error if you don't use locals then you can't get the login_error_msg key to view file